# Letting users login with facebook to an existing account

Tags: users, authentication-authorization, social-network

My client wants to add FaceBook integration into an existing site. I've successfully setup [fboauth](https://drupal.org/project/fboauth) and [openid_selector](https://drupal.org/project/openid_selector). New accounts can login without an issue. However, we liked to let an exiting user authorize a login from Facebook to their account.

I can see how to do this using `openid_selector`'s `http://yoursite.com//user/xxx/openid`. Might there be a way to duplicate this for FaceBook authentication?

[image]

**Update:** I found this node https://drupal.org/node/1624374. It seems that if a user is already logged into Drupal and then clicks the FB connect button, FBOauth will link the accounts. Though I'd prefer to have something like this managed through an interface like `openid_selector` (pictured in this post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuring OpenID for each services is so painful. I have also gone through the same process when I had to enable FB, Gmail & Twitter login at my website, but anyhow it was giving me problem even if I configured with the supported modules [oauth](https://drupal.org/project/oauth) & [connector](https://drupal.org/project/connector).

At last I found another module named [HYBRIDAUTH](https://drupal.org/project/hybridauth) & it worked so fine. Configuration is easy & there is no need of any other addon module with this. Best part is, it's free, otherwise most of the module of this kind are from some paid service provider..

Try this & I hope you will find all the services which you require along with facebook.

Comment: Dear lord I cannot believe how clean and organized that module is! Thank you.